# Prevent Page Refresh After Mobile Sleep/Wake

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

I have a web-app that does DOM manipulations. However, on mobile if you minimize the browser and close the phone's screen, after about 3-4 minutes when you open the browser again the page gets refreshed and any previous DOM changes are lost (the page loads to it's default state).

As a workaround I could use some AJAX to send the page changes via a ping to the database and then whenever the page loads - if the last ping was a certain time diff - load the changes.

However this is kinda tedious. Does anyone know of a way of just preventing the mobile browser from refreshing the page?

FYI I'm not using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The browser refreshing on mobile devices is not a thing of your website. This is mostly because the website needs to be in the storage of the mobile device to be displayed without refreshing. Mobile devices do not have that much RAM so the website will refresh on the most mobile browsers, you can't stop this.

What could help a little is to minimize the size of the website, if there is any way.